# how to send a file with a body

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, flask

I am working on React web app with a Flask backend. how can I send a file with JSON data on the body?
I try the code below but is not working

> ```
>         const file  = e.target.file[0]
>         const user = [{name: 'Ma'}]
>         const formData = new FormData()
>         dormData.append('file', file)
>         dormData.append('user', user)
>
>         const post =  await axios({
>             method: 'post',
>             url: 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/route',
>             data: formData,
>             headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" }
>         })
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the Content-Type header as `application/json` and you can set the body as your json

Your code would look something like this

```js
const post =  await axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/route',
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    body: JSON.stringify(myJson) //insert your stringified json here
})
```

Since you are creting a react web app, it's easy to structure a JSON from a form.

Comment: What error are you getting? Error messages are important, make sure you provide us error messages when stuff does not work

Answer (score 0):

You are spelling `formData` wrong. Use this code:

```
formData.append('file', file)
formData.append('user', user)
```

Comment: I changed the name but still the same. is not wotking